# Use AOS.js with class instead of data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animate-on-scroll, aos.js

I want to use AOS.js on my site but I have no option to add the necessary data attributes to the DIVs of the page.

Here's the markup from the docs (https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/):

```
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="3000">
    ...
</div>
```

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="aos-fade-up aos-duration-3000">
    ...
</div>
```

Is there any way to use AOS.js with only classes?

I found a similar question while researching: [Having trouble adding aos.js using classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885987/having-trouble-adding-aos-js-using-classes)
But there is no answer to that.

Here's the code from the other question but that doesn't work:

```
$('.aos-fade-up').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-aos', 'fade-up');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By taking a quick look at the issues in github and the source code (https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/blob/next/src/js/aos.js - https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/blob/next/src/js/helpers/elements.js) it seems that it only works using the `data-aos` attribute. If you'd rather use classes you could create an issue in the repo or tinker with the code yourself. Finally if your working with jQuery you might take a look at scroll magic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this snippet a try :

```
<script>
        function ismatch(str){
            var ret = null;
            var tab = ['data-aos_', 'data-aos-delay_', 'data-aos-duration_', 'data-aos-easing_'];
            Object.values(tab).forEach( function (value) {
                if (String(str).match(value)){
                    ret = str.split('_');
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return ret;
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.some-class').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var tab = $this.attr('class').split(' ');
                var keep;
                Object.values(tab).forEach(function (item) {
                    var ello = ismatch(item) 
                    if (ello !== null)
                        $this.attr(ello[0], ello[1]);
                    });
                    
                });
                AOS.init();
            });                     
    </script>
```

Usage :

````
<div class="some-class data-aos_fade-down data-aos-delay_100 data-aos-duration_800"></div>```
````